# search against tags and order by rank

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

`tags-table` has got three columns `web, tags, rank`

this table has got FULL TEXT SEARCH enabled

I am able to search by tags and get list of websites by this query

```
SELECT * FROM tags-table WHERE MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('search,searchengine,search,web' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but I want order the result by its rank. how do I do it??

I have tried this too but it gives something else.

```
SELECT * FROM tags-table WHERE MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('search,searchengine,search,web' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY ABS(rank)
```

by the by the `rank` column is filled with rank for respective sites. for example `google` has got `rank 1`, `facebook` hase got `rank2`, and `yahoo` has got `rank 4` like that for remaining sites.

```
tags-table




   web          |    tags                                       |     rank

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    google.com   |search,google,searchengine,engine,web          |     1
    facebook.com |facebook,social,networking,friends,community   |     2
    youtube.com  |video,youtube,videos,entertainment,media       |     3
    yahoo.com    |yahoo,search,email,news,searchengine           |     4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic column `rank`. But you can compute the relevance (or rank as you call it) like this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('search searchengine search web') AS relevance
FROM 
    tags-table 
WHERE 
    MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('+search +searchengine +search +web' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY 
    relevance DESC
```

Note that the first `MATCH AGAINST` is not run `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. That is because `IN BOOLEAN MODE` almost always returns 1.

Comment: there is a rank column and rank is mentioned in that column. for example google has got rant 1 and facebook has got rank 2 etc...